# XNA flip SpriteBatch on click

Tags: xna, c#, windows-phone-7

Is there any way to make a `SpriteBatch` flip when its clicked, something like [Android Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/package-summary.html)?

I know that `spriteBatch.Draw()` have `SpriteEffects`, but it literally flip it and I want to flip it like an animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XNA, you won't find any direct analog to the Android method you linked.  You are also correct that [`SpriteEffects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spriteeffects.aspx) is not the answer to your problem (it's a very short enumeration).

If you want to display an animation, you will have to manually display different sprites sequentially, which is commonly accomplished with a sprite sheet that contains the frames.  You must implement some form of a counter that updates each frame, and use that counter to select the correct frame of your animation.  For example, if the animation frames are arranged into a grid, you could progress through that grid's rows and columns using a pair of simple loops (again, based on your counter).